# Allow and disallow in robots.txt file

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, search-engine-bots

I want to disallow all files and folders on my site from SE bots, except a special folder and files in it.
Can I use these lines at robots.txt file?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /thatfolder
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User-agent:* 
Allow: /thatfolder
Disallow: /
```

This should do. (just changed the order)

Comment: Why does this work? can you explain a little bit? I found in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-lines) that the least restriction trumps when a conflict between entries is done, so I think that the Allow is always less restrictive than Disallow. So the @hd. is wrong because the order of Allow and Disallow? so, if allow is not above disallow is completely ignored?

Comment: TBH, It's been a decade! The current docs don't seem to care about the order much. However, I'd like to test it out to confirm that. If you could test both the cases and post it, I'll update the answer or you can post your own answer and have OP mark it. Thanks! Good job on reading the docs. Appreciate linking it! (I should have done that in the first place when I answered)